# Merging two lists of tuples of different size into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, nested-lists

Now I have two lists of tuples of different size like this:

```
a = [('NC', 0, 'Eyes'),('NC', 3, 'organs'),('NC', 19, 'neurons'),...]
b = [(0, 'Hypernym', 3),(19, 'Holonym', 0),...]
```

The common values from the above lists is the int number, and the expected result should look like:

```
result = [
    {'s_type':'NC', 's':'Eyes', 'predicate':'Hypernym', 'o_type':'NC', 'o':'organs'},
    {'s_type':'NC', 's':'neurons', 'predicate':'Holonym', 'o_type':'NC', 'o':'Eyes'},
    ...]
```

I have converted the above two lists into dictionaries and tried nested loop but failed to get this output. Can somebody kindly help me out?

Comment: s_type is not even in the input

Comment: @anon01 For tuple in list a, tuple[0] denotes the type of an entity, tuple[1] denotes the position of an entity and tuple[2] denotes the entity. For tuple in list b, tuple[0] denotes the position of the entity1, tuple[1] denotes the relation between entity1 and entity2 while tuple[2] denotes the position of the entity2. Sorry for the unclear description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this one working. Let me know if there are any other specifics that need fixing.

```
a = [('NC', 0, 'Eyes'), ('NC', 3, 'organs'), ('NC', 19, 'neurons')]
b = [(0, 'Hypernym', 3), (19, 'Holonym', 0)]

result = []

for s_type, common, s in a:
    related = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == common, b))
    for o_type, predicate, next in related:
        next_related = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == next, a))
        for s_type, _, organ in next_related:
            result.append({'s_type': s_type, 's': s,
                           'predicate': predicate, 'o_type': o_type, 'o': organ})

print(result)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.
There are many other ways to do this, but given your description of the problem, this should do.

Comment: @WenMa glad I could help. Hope everything was clear. An upvote or answer accepted would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt elegant solution. Your answer is almost what I was looking for. Due to the unclear description, a tiny change will make the answer fulfill my expected output: **result.append({'s_type': s_type, 's': s, 'predicate': predicate, 'o_type': s_type, 'o': organ})**. In this case, it's better to rename all the variables to avoid confusion. Because in the filtered related list, the first element actually is the position of entity1(or subject), not the type of entity2(or object). It's really kind of you to help me out!

Comment: @WenMa no worries. Helping is what this community is about :)